# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am getting *'Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException'* as response when I am trying to check if the validator works. So when after I click the save button. This is my code :

**in my view 'addMedia-partial.blade.php'**  :

```
         {{ Form::open() }}

            <input type="text" name="videoUrl" placeholder="enter youtube video url" />
            <input type="text" name="videoTitle" placeholder="enter video title" />
            <input type="text" name="videoDescription" placeholder="enter video description" />

            <input type="submit" value="Save">

        {{ Form::close() }}
```

**in my routes.php :**

```
Route::get('/guide/dashboard/media/add/storeVideo', array('as' => 'guide-video-add','uses' => 'MediaController@getNewVideo'));
Route::post('/guide/dashboard/media/add/storeVideo', array('uses' => 'MediaController@postNewVideo'));
```

**in my controller MediaController.php :**

```
public function postNewVideo() 
{

        $rules = array('videoUrl' => 'required', 'videoTitle' => 'required|min:5', 'videoDescription' => 'required|min:20');

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {


            //return Redirect::route('guide-media-add')->withErrors($validator);
            //gaat niet omdat dit in een andere controller is ?? 

            return Redirect::route('guide-video-add')->withErrors($validator);

        }
}

public function getNewVideo()
{
    return View::make('guide.dashboard.dashboard')->nest('child', 'guide.dashboard.addMedia-partial');
}
```

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel` this simply means you are confused with `get` and `post`

Comment: When did you get the error? after submit the form?

Comment: yes when I tried to submit with validation errors , to check if the validation is working

Comment: I really don't see where I have made a mistake with a get and post.

Comment: Ensure your form's `method` attribute is set to `post`. I think this *is* the default in Laravel so it's confusing that it's going wrong, but just check the actual HTML output to be sure (or watch the HTTP requests in your browser's 'network' inspector).

Comment: Where is the `action` value of the form? You might need to view the source code to find the value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with Firebug which URL and which type of request are you sending.

Secondly please execute `php artisan route:list` This will show you all the routes and which method they accept.

There must be mismatch between defined and actual requests. You must be sending POST to the route which only accepts GET.